# How to save System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection instance to hard disk and load it back as an instance?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have following instance of System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection:

```
Dim UserSelection As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

UserSelection.Add("D_Color1", "Black")
UserSelection.Add("D_Color2", "Green")
UserSelection.Add("D_Color3", "Purple")
```

I need to save this instance to hard disk and then load it back from hard disk as an instance. How do I do that?

Comment: Why a byte array? If you need it to deserialize back to a NameValueCollection again that doesn't require a byte array.

Comment: how about xml?  Its the new way to save ;-)

Comment: @CrazyDart We probably shouldn't recommend using new untested technologies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the BinaryFormatter

```
Using fs As New FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create)
   Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
   formatter.Serialize(fs, UserSelection)
End Using
```

And to deserialize

```
Using fs As New FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open)
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
    UserSelection = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(fs), NameValueCollection)
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

Through the magic of [Serializible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you can write a collection to a serialized format, save that to disk, send it over the network, whatever, and then deserialize it back into a new instance of NameValueCollection. Because of the way Serializable is written, you can control just how it is persisted. To get it serializing to XML you have to write (or google for) a small bit of code which [implements IXmlSerializable for a NameValueCollection](http://weblogs.asp.net/george_v_reilly/archive/2007/07/19/serializing-a-namevaluecollection.aspx). Serializing to [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) works out of the box:

```
 Dim fs as New FileStream("MyNameValueCollection.bin", FileMode.Create)
 Dim bs as New BinaryFormatter()
 bs.Serialize(fs, UserSelection)
 fs.Close()
```

Comment: How is this not useful? Links to the relevant documentation, and examples of both XML & binary as the OP didn't realize he could use something other than a byte array.

Comment: Thanks Predator, was trying to figure out why someone voted it down

Comment: +1 It's a good explanation and does not deserve a minus I think. Only problem is that `NameValueCollection` is not XML serializable.

Comment: @Magnus You're right. That is very odd, it is serializable but doesn't implement IXmlSerializable, even though it can only contain strings and so would be trivial to support Xml serialization.